# Is it possible to handle text translations for data stored in database tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, translation

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to know *if it is possible to handle text translations for data stored in database tables*. **Is it possible? If so, how?**

For example, if I have a database table column named `Title` and in that I have a record with the `Title` value set\stored to "*car*", I would like to show

- the text "*automobile*" for italian people;
- the text "*auto*" for german people;
- and so on...

Comment: Is it possible? Of course it is. How? Well work that out for yourself by reading all the other posts on SO on how to do this, there are many, look at other frameworks that are FOSS to see how they deal with it, look at the built in solutions in ROR for internationalisation and then build something based on your new found knowledge, understanding and research. At this point when you have a nearly working solution and maybe it is just sticking somewhere then come back to SO and ask a question that will have an answer and shows you know how to work things out for yourself.

Comment: @PurplePilot - Can you provide at least some link to Web resources where I can know more information about my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For user generated content it's best to store the language with the content.

You can then have your users create "copies" of this data with a different language reference.

Depending on how much data you need to change per table a different gems might be suitable for your needs. I18n gem is NOT a good choice here, as it's meant for static content. See: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/i18n

Answer (score 0):

Ruby can help you translate the words from one language to another, but only by providing hashes and structures or code algorithms that allow you to do lookups. By itself it knows nothing of the meaning of words, and cannot translate words.

For your purpose, you should build a table of translations, with the primary language words in a primary field, and their translations in secondary fields, one field for each language. Then you can quickly look up all the words for a form in German, or Italian, and substitute them into the form.

Comment: So, do you mean that the process is that RoR can "auto-check" for words (stated in a proper YAML file) after retrieving a text from the database?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "auto-check". There is no auto-check; You tell Rails or Ruby to retrieve the words for the database for a form in a needed language based on the settings your user selected when their account was set up. It's just like filling in fields in an ERB or HAML template, only you're not using the English words, you're using the words from another language.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your rails application for internationalization using Rails Internationalization (i18n) API. You would need to pass and set the locale. The locale files would reside in config/locales. As mentioned by the tin Man, the locale file is a key:value file. Here you can override custom rails defaults.

Locale can be set from params and also from domain name. The Rails guide is actually the best place to start with in my opinion.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the other answers, you'll want to use the rails i18n functionality to get this to work.

There are however alternative ways of storing your translations. [This railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends) describes how to set up a redis-based translation backend, as well as links to a whole bunch of different backends.

If you just want to store your translations in a database using ActiveRecord, I'd suggest you have a look at [i18n-active_record](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record).

With these plugins you can easily store your translations in the database, and have your application look them up for you using `I18n.t('some_translation_key')`.